# symfony 2 Set remember me on post auto login on registration

Tags: symfony, authentication, registration, remember-me, symfony-2.4

I am using Symfony 2.4. After a user registers I need to log him in and automatically and also have the remember me functionality enabled as well along with it.

at the moment to login I use the following code

$token = new UsernamePasswordToken($fb_userByEmail, $fb_userByEmail->getPassword(), 'member_area', $fb_userByEmail->getRoles());
            $this->get('security.context')->setToken($token);
            $this->get('session')->set('_security_member_area', serialize($token));

but I need the remember me functionality as well.

the RememberMeToken doesn't seem to help in this case as well.

Comment: Ok, so what have you tried and what did it do wrong?

Comment: i have tried the RememberMeToken thing but it does not do anything. The user gets logged in after signup but the RememberMe cookie is still not set.